# Dart support for using Script Property Values in Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, dart

The [Unicode regular expression documentation](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/) describes doing complex matches for text. Specifically, I am wondering about matching various scripts within a string of text based on the script property values of the code points.

The Unicode documentation about [Using Script Property Values in Regular Expressions](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Script_Names_in_RegEx) refers to this possibility:

> The script property is useful in regular expression syntax for easy
>   specification of spans of text that consist of a single script or
>   mixture of scripts. In general, regular expressions should use
>   specific Script property values only in conjunction with both Common
>   and Inherited. For example, to distinguish a sequence of characters
>   appropriate for Greek text, one might use
>
> ((Greek | Common) (Inherited | Me | Mn)*)*
>
> The preceding expression matches all characters that have a Script
>   property value of Greek or Common and which are optionally followed by
>   characters with a Script property value of Inherited. For
>   completeness, the regular expression also allows any nonspacing or
>   enclosing mark.
>
> Some languages commonly use multiple scripts, so, for example, to
>   distinguish a sequence of characters appropriate for Japanese text one
>   might use:
>
> ((Hiragana | Katakana | Han | Latin | Common) (Inherited | Me | Mn)*)*

Is this implemented in Dart? I don't see it described for Dart [RegEx](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) or for [JavaScript ECMAScript regex specs](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10) that Dart regexes are based on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart added support for Unicode properties in version 2.4 back in mid-2019 (see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34935). However, there is a gotcha: for this to work you need to pass the optional argument "unicode: true" to the RegExp() constructor in order to identify your pattern as a "unicode pattern". I've tested the following (which matches {L} letters, {N} numbers and {M} marks) and it works fine with the latest Dart SDK:

```
RegExp(r'[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]', unicode: true)
```

To match Greek characters, as per @daxim's example:

```
RegExp exp = RegExp(r'(\p{Script=Greek})', unicode: true);
Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches;
matches = exp.allMatches('ΓβγΔδΕεζηΘθ');
for (Match m in matches) {
  print('${m.group(1)}');
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Any idea why @dahim's example still doesn't work even when adding `unicode: true`?

Comment: @Suragch: Yes, the problem is that the reg exp string should be ```'\p{Script=Greek}'``` instead of ```'\p{Script:Greek}'``` to capture Greek letters. I have updated my answer to show a tested, working example of this. Cheers!

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The most simple case is not supported, let alone set operations. Tested with https://dartpad.dev/

```
void main() {
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"(\p{Script:Greek})");
  String str = "Γ";
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(str);
  for (Match m in matches) {
    final match = m.group(0);
    print(match);
  }
}
```

Got: no result

Expect: Γ

---

[Use Perl](http://p3rl.org/recharclass#Extended-Bracketed-Character-Classes) when you don't want to be disappointed.

Comment: I don't know Dart and I could be doing something wrong, [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57586805/edit) from people more knowledgeable than me are much appreciated.

Comment: Dart does support this since mid-2019, but you have to pass the optional argument "unicode: true" to the RegExp() constructor, and you have to use "\p{Script=Greek}" instead of "\p{Script:Greek}" to capture Greek letters. Cheers...